# ps2pdf not working in TextStudio

Tags: miktex, texstudio, ghostscript, ps2pdf

System information:

1. Windows XP Professiona (Service Pack 3), 32 bit
2. TexStudio 2.11.2
3. MikTex 2.9
4. GPL Ghostscript 9.20 (32 bit)

I have configure TexStudio's "Build & View" to DVI>PS>PDF Chain.

When I am compiling the .tex file, the .ps file gets generated. Then TexStudio is trying to run ps2pdf command on the generated .ps file to generate the corresponding .pdf file and it gets an error, saying - "C:\Program Files\MikTex 2.9\miktex\bin\mgs.exe is not a valid Win32 application". And it does not generate the .pdf. However, when I am trying to convert the .ps file using other program (Arobat Distiller), .pdf file is generated correctly which means the .ps file is absolutely correct.

I have digged in many online posts to solve this issue on my own, but with no success. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Welcome! It is complaining about the application `mgs.exe` - not the file. Try converting on the command line with whatever verbose/debug flags you can. But it looks like there's something wrong with that binary. Maybe reinstall it using MikTeX's manager thingy? Or make sure everything is up to date? Check the binary is 32 bit and not 64.